# Add an element when "DOMNodeInserted" event called

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, dom

I want to add an element after every "like" button (chrome extension). Since posts are added to the news feed without refreshing the page, I have to add an event listener "`DOMNodeInserted`". But when I try to put the `after()` function inside it, it doesn't work.

Code:

```
    $("#contentArea").addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
        $(".like_link").after('<span class="dot"> · </span><button class="taheles_link stat_elem as_link" title="תגיד תכל&acute;ס" type="submit" name="taheles" onclick="apply_taheles()" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;&gt;&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:22}"><span class="taheles_default_message">תכל&acute;ס</span><span class="taheles_saving_message">לא תכלס</span></button>');
        $(".taheles_saving_message").hide(); 
    });
```

When I change `$("#contentArea")` to `document` it crashes all the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want to add an event listener in jQuery, that is not the method, the corect way should always be:

```
$(document or window).bind( your_event_name, function(event) { your_callback });
```

with this in mind, you can write:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {

    alert('inserted ' + event.target.nodeName + // new node
          ' in ' + event.relatedNode.nodeName); // parent

});
```

or do what you need to perform every time a node is inserted in the DOM.

---

for your information, if you want to use `addEventListener` you need to use plain javascript and not jQuery.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function () {
    // your code
}, false);
```

**Edit:** As on jQuery 1.7, please use the '.on' function instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/

---

another error that comes up of your method (if it worked) is that you will break your application as you are **inserting a node** and call the `DOMNodeInserted` (cause you have inserted a node) and that will insert the node again, and call the `DOMNodeInserted` again...

you can see what is going on ...

I would suggest that you listen to the correct method and append your `span` there...

Comment: If I use the second method, what function should I use instead of after() in jQuery?

Comment: you can't insert a node inside your listener for `DOMNodeInserted` or you get an infinite loop... after you use the `.after()` to insert the new node, the `DOMNodeInserted` will be called again (as you have inserted a DOM node) and so on, and on, and on...

Comment: yes you are right, do you have any suggestion? I already tried many things like setInterval()...

Comment: suggest of what? you do not say what you want to do ... and if I'm write, you should upvote ;) - maybe you can ask something different in a new question no? And then leave the url of your new question here, so I can have a look what are you trying to do...

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674079/domnodeinserted-event-loop)

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing problem that your code under runs only once in jquery .on() function then your should put it under addEventListner like below example //

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    $("selector").on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e)   {
       //your code which you want to execute each time DOMNodeInserted
    });
});
```