# DOMNodeInserted event loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-events

I am developing a chrome extension (my fourth question or so...) for facebook, which adds a custom button beside the "like" button. Since posts are added automatically to the news feed without a page refresh, I have to add the script every time new posts are added.

And I use `DOMNodeInserted` event.

The problem is that when the event is called I insert a new element (the button) to the page and it makes a loop!

My script:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    $(".like_link").after('<span class="dot"> · </span><button class="taheles_link stat_elem as_link" title="תגיד תכל&acute;ס" type="submit" name="taheles" onclick="apply_taheles()" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;&gt;&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:22}"><span class="taheles_default_message">תכל&acute;ס</span><span class="taheles_saving_message">לא תכלס</span></button>');
    $(".taheles_saving_message").hide();
});
```

You can see my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667935/add-an-element-when-domnodeinserted-event-called/10667964)

I'm tired of asking questions so I'll really appreciate any answer/comment!

Comment: You might want to use the [liveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin here. Then again, that seem to not use this event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? Providing that you don't insert any more `.like_link` elements, this should be a no-op when your element insertion happens, since it only looks for node insertions which contain a  `.like_link`.

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    $(event.target).find(".like_link").after(
        '<span class="dot"> · </span>' +
        '<button class="taheles_link stat_elem as_link" title="תגיד תכל&acute;ס" type="submit" name="taheles" onclick="apply_taheles()" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;&gt;&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:22}">' +
            '<span class="taheles_default_message">תכל&acute;ס</span><span class="taheles_saving_message">לא תכלס</span>' +
        '</button>'
    );
    $(event.target).find(".taheles_saving_message").hide();
});
```